# Running multiple concurrent GMainLoops

Tags: c, multithreading, glib

Are users of GLib allowed to run multiple `GMainLoop` instances concurrently in multiple threads, with each thread running its own instance?  I've found "yes" and "no" answers all over the place. I realize that this question has been asked before in this very forum [(December 2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529483/possible-to-run-multiple-main-loops).

However, I am able to run two `GMainLoop` instances at the same time without apparent issue.  My test code is very simple:

1. Create a `GMainLoop` in `main()`
2. Create a timeout source for the default context and the main loop using `g_timeout_add`
3. Create a GThread in main()
4. Run the main loop using `g_main_loop_run`
5. [THREAD CONTEXT]: Create a context using `g_main_context_new`
6. [THREAD CONTEXT]: Set that context as the thread default using   `g_main_context_push_thread_default`
7. [THREAD CONTEXT]: Create a loop using `g_main_loop_new` and give it the new context
8. [THREAD CONTEXT]: Create a timeout source, and attach it to the new context via   `g_source_attach`.
9. [THREAD_CONTEXT]: Have the thread invoke `g_main_loop_run`

Doing this, I see both instances of the `GMainLoop` working just fine.  The timeout callbacks are invoked correctly, and later calls to g_main_loop_quit work as expected.

So, it looks like it is not a problem to have multiple `GMainLoop` instances working concurrently.  But perhaps I just haven't exercised the API enough to fully grasp the situation. Is there a definitive answer to this question?

Also, here's the actual test code if anybody cares to look:

```
#define THREAD_TIMEOUTS (20)
#define MAIN_TIMEOUS (1)

typedef struct timeout_struct
{
    int i;
    int max;
    GMainLoop *loop;
    char *name;

} TIMEOUT_STRUCT;

gboolean timeout_callback(gpointer data)
{
    TIMEOUT_STRUCT *psTimeout = (TIMEOUT_STRUCT *)data;

    psTimeout->i++;

    if (psTimeout->i == psTimeout->max)
    {
        if (psTimeout->max == THREAD_TIMEOUTS)
        {
            g_main_loop_quit( (GMainLoop*)psTimeout->loop );
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
void* thread_function(void *data)
{
    GMainContext *ps_context;
    GMainLoop *ps_loop;
    GSource *ps_timer;
    TIMEOUT_STRUCT sTimeout;

    ps_context = g_main_context_new();
    g_main_context_push_thread_default(ps_context);

    ps_loop = g_main_loop_new(ps_context, FALSE);

    sTimeout.i = 0;
    sTimeout.max = THREAD_TIMEOUTS;
    sTimeout.loop = ps_loop;
    sTimeout.name = "thread";
    ps_timer = g_timeout_source_new_seconds(1);
    g_source_set_callback(ps_timer, timeout_callback, &sTimeout, NULL);
    g_source_attach(ps_timer, ps_context);

    g_main_loop_run(ps_loop);

    g_main_loop_quit( (GMainLoop*)data );

    return NULL;

}
/*
 * This main boots a thread, then starts up a GMainLoop.  Then the thread runs
 * a GMainLoop.  The thread sets a timer that fires ten times and the main sets a
 * timer that fires two times. The thread quits and
 * and then the other main l
 *
 *
 * */
int main()
{
    GThread *ps_thread;
    GMainLoop *loop;
    TIMEOUT_STRUCT sTimeout;

    loop = g_main_loop_new ( NULL , FALSE );

    sTimeout.i = 0;
    sTimeout.max = MAIN_TIMEOUS;
    sTimeout.loop = loop;
    sTimeout.name = "main";

    // add source to default context
    g_timeout_add (1 , timeout_callback, &sTimeout);

    ps_thread = g_thread_new("thread", thread_function, loop);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
}
```

Comment: I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286284/g-timeout-add-inside-a-gthread) which appears to agree that this is acceptable usage of the GLib API.  So, another entry in the "yes, this is fine" column I guess.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The book "Foundations of GTK+ Development" states this:

> The GLib main loop is implemented as a number of structures, which allow multiple instances
>   to be run concurrently.

So, given this, my test code, and the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286284/g-timeout-add-inside-a-gthread) I posted in the comment above we have a definitive answer to this question.

Namely: Multiple threads may have their own GMainContext & GMainLoop, and are able to independently run these loops in a concurrent fashion.