# gst_element_link faild in second thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gstreamer, ip-camera

I have problem with linking elements in second thread.
I create two thread in each I create pipeline to store IP camera stream to file.
When second thread try link stream element (h264parse -> matroskamux ) I recieve Segmentation fault signal.

Gstreamer print some error:

```
(Cam_recorder:5529): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GstMatroskamuxPad'

(Cam_recorder:5529): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

When I run same code with added some delay (500ms) between execution thread, both thread create pipeline correctly and program work.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
My code:

```
void Camera::Thread_function(){
    GstElement *pipeline=NULL;
    GstElement * temp_ele;
    GstBus *bus=NULL;
    GstMessage *msg=NULL;
    GError *error = NULL;
    STRING text;
    DEBUG<<"Starting camera:"<<name<<END;
    text=stream_uri;
    DEBUG<< text <<END;
    pipeline=gst_parse_launch(text.c_str(),&error);
    if (error != NULL){
        CRITICAL<<"Parse error: "<< error->message<<END;
        g_error_free (error);
        error=NULL;
        goto STOP;
    }

    if(pipeline==NULL){
        CRITICAL<<"Pipeline is NULL"<<END;
        goto STOP;
    }

     gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

     loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
     gst_bus_add_watch (GST_ELEMENT_BUS (pipeline), bus_cb, loop);
     g_timeout_add_seconds (1, CAM_REC::timeout_cb, this);
     g_main_loop_run (loop);
     g_main_loop_unref (loop);
STOP:

    if (msg != NULL){
      gst_message_unref (msg);
      msg=NULL;
    }
    if(bus!=NULL){
        gst_object_unref (bus);
        bus=NULL;
    }

    if(pipeline){
        gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
        gst_object_unref (pipeline);
        pipeline=NULL;
    }
    //*/
    INFO<<"Cam "<<name<<" end"<<END;
}
```

Pipelines:

```
rtspsrc name=kam3_stream  location=\"rtsp://192.168.0.107/stream1\" ! rtph264depay name=kam3_deplay ! h264parse name=kam3_parse ! matroskamux name=kam3_mux ! filesink location=x.mkv name=kamera3_file_sink

rtspsrc name=kam4_stream  location=\"rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.108/\" ! rtph264depay name=kam4_deplay ! h264parse name=kam4_parse ! matroskamux name=kam4_mux ! filesink location=x2.mkv name=kamera4_file_sink
```

Program crashes in function gst_parse_launch()

Tank

Comment: I change my code to simply make 2 thread witch call  gst_parse_launch() and same behaviour

Comment: please add some reference code.. which is causing the problem..

Comment: I dont know if its ok to have two main loops (the g_main_loop's) - what about move the g_main_loop_new/_run calls outside the threads? or share the loop somehow..

Comment: I may have mislead you with my earlier answer regarding multiple pipelines.  I'm gonna remove it.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485642/running-multiple-concurrent-gmainloops